# Run class viewDidLoad method from push button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class, viewdidload

I was wondering how can you load a class in objective-c from another class? I have a push action button in one and when the users presses this I want it to start this other Class (calling its viewDidLoad method)

Comment: what do "load a class" and "start a class" mean to you ?

Comment: viewDidLoad would be called when you first allocate an instance of a class. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: i followed this example (http://bit.ly/xLioOG) to set up a "book". I want to open this book from an interface using a button. So i'd want to 'start/call' the PageViewController

Comment: @Vin not true - it would be called after the view has been loaded (hence the name). I could instantiate a view controller and never present/push it and therefore it will never have it's `viewDidLoad` called. This is also only applicable for subclasses of `UIViewController`

Comment: @Paul.s agree with you. In the question he mentioned that he was already doing a push action.

Comment: @Vin I didn't really read the question because it needs more detail to be answered. I was just commenting on your comment `viewDidLoad would be called when you first allocate an instance of a class`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more precise.

What kind of classes are you manipulating ? `UIViewControllers` ?

If so, you can `alloc`/`init` (or `alloc`/`initWithNibName` if you are using Interface Builder) the second ViewController when your button is pushed. The `viewDidLoad` method will be called when the view of the second view controller will be loaded (not necessarily when the `viewController` is allocated, but when the view will be displayed for the first time).

If you need the execute the code in the `viewDidLoad` method every time the button is pushed, prefere using the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the classes which are subclass of `UIViewController` then you can load view of another view controller by pushing it into the navigation controller object. Also you can add the view of the second controller on the first controller view.